# Xcode 11 Beta 4 Archive errors

Tags: xcode

I have this exact issue when I try to archive my project

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
```

In xCode release notes they mentioned this workaround but it didn't work for me

> Targets that contain Swift code with the Enable Bitcode build setting
>   set to Yes fail to link correctly when built with the Archive action.
>   (52804818)
>
> Workaround: Add a custom build setting with the name
>   LD_VERIFY_BITCODE, and set it to NO. Make a note to yourself to delete
>   this custom build setting once this issue is resolved.

Comment: Well you’re not alone, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227953/why-is-my-app-returning-hundreds-of-errors-that-say-undefinedsymbol

Comment: Beta 5 is released and it contains a fix for this issue, here's a snapshot from the release notes "Targets containing Swift code with the Enable Bitcode build setting set to Yes link correctly when built with the Archive action. (52804818)"

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for reporting back.